# Updating dojox.mobile.Heading label

Tags: mobile, dojo

I have a header defined like so:

```
<h1 id=header" dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading" back="Back" moveTo="group1" label="Old Header"></h1>
```

I want to change the label of the header in an onClick event. I first tried this:

```
var header = dijit.byId("header");
header.innerHTML = "New Header";
```

This updated the label correctly but my back button disappeared because it was rendered in a  that was in the innerHTML (which is now "New Header").

I tried another approach, using dojox.mobile.Heading.setLabel():

```
var header = dijit.byId("header");
header.setLabel("New Header");
```

This keeps the back button but does not actually change the label. When inspect console.log(header) I can see label was changed but it does not show up on my page. Its like header needs to "redraw" itself. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if helps, but I can change the label with setLabel without a problem EXCEPTS when my header have the "back" attribute.

Answer (score 3):

try `header.set("label", "New Header");`

Answer (score -1):

This is a hack that solve my problem (see the comment above).

```
  dijit.byId('header').domNode.lastChild.nodeValue = 'New label';
```